# Both buttons decrementing same value

Tags: php, html

I am buildingd a library management system in PHP and HTMl.
 I have some problem with the borrowing system where user can borrow books.
Here is my emitere-carti.php:

```
<form action="imprumutare.php" method="POST">
          <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>

         <th>Imprumutare</th>
          <th scope="col">Titlu </th>
          <th scope="col">Autor</th>
           <th scope="col">Categorie</th>
           <th scope="col">Stoc</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
         <?php

    $selectare="SELECT * FROM carti";
    $rezultat=mysqli_query($conn,$selectare);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rezultat)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)){
    $carte_nume=$row['titlu'];
    $disabled=$row['stoc']>0 ? "" :"disabled";

?>  

<tr>

    <td><input type="submit" name="test" class="btn btn-secondary" 
       value="Imprumutare" <?php echo $disabled;?>></input>
    <td><input type="text" name="nume" value="<?php echo $row['titlu'];? 
    >"></input></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['autor'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['categorie'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['stoc'];?></td>
         </tr>
       <?php
        }
        }      
        ?>
        </tbody>

         </table>
        </form>
```

Here is my imprumutare.php(that means borrowing):

```
include('conexiune.php');

//sfarsit if
//Imprumutare
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    $id=$_POST['identificator'];
    $nume_carte=$_POST['nume'];
    $sql_rezervare="UPDATE carti SET stoc=stoc-1 WHERE 
             titlu='$nume_carte'  ";
    if( mysqli_query($conn,$sql_rezervare)){
        header('location:emitere_carti.php');
    }
    else{
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot about what I am talking:
[image]

So my problem is both buttons are decrementeing the same value(the value of stoc).
Can someone help me?

Comment: Formatting and properly indenting your code is highly recommended. It makes the code easier to read and therefore easier to help.

Comment: Where is `name=identificator` in the form?

Comment: i can see only one button in the code !!

Comment: @zod It's in a loop.

Comment: Does the user really need to be able to edit the book title?

Comment: Put the book title or ID in the value of the submit button. Then you can use `$_POST['test']` to know which Imprumature button they clicked on.

Comment: @Barmar i was thinking like one increment and one decrement button ..my bad! now issue is clear !